# Testing angularjs directive (template not updated in tests after changing an isolated scope var)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating an angularjs component that (will) provides a checkbox list directive with filtering, sorting, toggling options, scrolling, etc... once finished. It should help people to deal with long checkbox lists.

I'm trying to test the order by label or id feature but the template does not reflect the model changes even after $digest or $apply call. I tried to solve but no way.

Here it is the directive definition:

```
angular.module('angularjsSmartcheckboxApp')
  .directive('smartCheckbox', [function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/smartcheckbox.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {model: '='},
      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        // TODO
      }]
    };
  }]);
```

Usage:

```
<smart-checkbox model="smartList" />
```

where smartList is:

```
$scope.smartList = [
    {id: '001', label: 'First item'},
    {id: '002', label: 'Second item'},
    {id: 'Z01', label: 'Another item'}
  ];
```

Here is the template:

```
...
<div class="input-group ordercontrols">
  Order options:
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="label" ng-model="orderby"> Label
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="id" ng-model="orderby"> Id
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="reverse" />
    Reverse
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="checkbox widgetcontrols" ng-repeat="elem in model | filter:{$:filter} | orderBy: orderby:reverse">
    <label>
      <input class="smart" type="checkbox" ng-model="elem.value" value="{{elem.value || false}}" />
      <span class="itemid">[{{elem.id}}]</span> {{elem.label}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you can find the failing test 'Labels order (reverse)':

```
describe('Directive: smartCheckbox', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('angularjsSmartcheckboxApp', 'views/smartcheckbox.html'));

  var element,
    $rootScope,
    $compile,
    scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope.model = [
        {id: '001', label:'First item'},
        {id: '002', label:'Second item'}
    ];

    element = $compile(angular.element('<smart-checkbox model="model"></smart-checkbox>'))(scope);
    $rootScope.$apply();

  }));

  it('Labels order (reverse)', function () {

    scope.reverse = true;
    scope.orderby = 'label';
    scope.$apply();

    expect(element.children().eq(3).find('label').eq(0).find('span').text()).toBe('[002]');
  });
});
```

Repository link:
https://github.com/davidemoro/angularjs-smartcheckbox

PS: if you open the browser the reordering works fine, so I suppose there is something of wrong in the test method.

What is the problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what is `element.children()`, what is the actual text content of the first span etc ?

Comment: Yes, I did: the elements are listed in the wrong order (launching the real app it's all fine). It seems that the $digest loop is not able to detect changes on label or orderby during tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How I solved it:

```
-    element = $compile(angular.element('<smart-checkbox model="model"></smart-checkbox>'))(scope);
+    $element = angular.element('<smart-checkbox model="model"></smart-checkbox>');
+    element = $compile($element)(scope);

...

   it('Labels order (reverse)', function () {

-    scope.reverse = true;
-    scope.orderby = 'label';
-    scope.$apply();
+    $element.isolateScope().reverse = true;
+    $element.isolateScope().orderby = 'label';
+    $element.isolateScope().$apply();

-    expect(element.children().eq(3).find('label').eq(0).find('span').text()).toBe('[002]');
+    expect($element.children().eq(3).find('label').eq(0).find('span').text()).toBe('[002]');
   });
```

Since the directive uses an isolated scope, I need to use the .isolateScope method.
Hope it might help other people :)

UPDATE: I've writed a blog post based on this answer. See http://davidemoro.blogspot.com/2014/02/testing-angularjs-directives-with_13.html